# Django haystack load_all not getting foreign key

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-haystack

I am using haystack 2.1 on django for my website. I use the SearchQueryset to filter results according to user input from search form. The I do results.load_all() to select the objects from database. But the problem I am facing is that the

```
sqs.load_all()

for each in results:
   {{ each.object.user.id }}
```

for each object, the user is selected by a separate query from database. 
I am unable to specify the level of select_related in load_all of sqs. Is this possible. Please give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation [here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/searchqueryset_api.html) says you can use `select_related`:

```
sqs = RelatedSearchQuerySet().filter(content='foo').load_all()
sqs = sqs.load_all_queryset(Entry, Entry.objects.all().select_related(depth=1))
```